# How to get rid of the Ender Dragon spawned under the bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I spawned the Ender Dragon under the bedrock in 1.12.2 by mistake and the commands don't seem to work. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

### Do this in the end dimension:

```
/kill @e[type=ender_dragon]
```

(made with mc stacker)

It should kill all of the ender dragons in the game, including the one you want to get rid of.